# Joomla 3 over ride of category blog layout

Tags: php, blogs, joomla3.0

I am using Joomla 3 and I am trying to override the layout on the category blog page for one section of my site. I can see that the code lives in:

```
 \templates\protostar\html\layouts\joomla\content\blog_style_default_item_title.php
```

When I open the menu item I see there is an option for Template style. Do I need to create a whole new folder under templates to get a unique layout for this particular category blog page or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy just the view into your template *html* folder. Refer to http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core for details.

For different layouts on different category blog pages, do the same process as above but when copying the layout files you want to override in the template folder, change the filename, then it will be available as another layout to choose from in the backend.

Comment: I have already done this. I am trying to achieve different layouts on different category blog pages. How does one achieve this?

Comment: OK. So are you saying I need to copy:

blog_style_default_item_title.php 

Into the same folder? Im not quite sure how this is supposed to work?